# Need jGrid with Json

Tags: json

I got JGrid which works for table and not for the Json format, does any one have json version for

http://www.overset.com/2008/08/30/animated-sortable-datagrid-jquery-plugin-jtps/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

here is the example

```
{ 
  total: "xxx", 
  page: "yyy", 
  records: "zzz",
  rows : [
    {id:"1", cell:["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {id:"2", cell:["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
}
```

You can found this information at the following link:

http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm

That example is the default json readear, but you can modify it